# How do I merge the the two values of two objects that share a common key together and return it?

Tags: javascript, object

Write a function called mergeCounters which accepts two objects where all of the values are numbers and returns a new object with the total of both objects.
The order of your returned object does not matter, as long as it contains the correct keys and values!

```js
function mergeCounters (object1, object2) {
  var myObj = {};
  for (key in obj1) {
    for (key2 in obj2) {
      var val = myObj[key + key2];
    }
  }
  return myObj;
}

var obj1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3};
var obj2 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj1, obj2)); // {a:4, b:8, c:10}

var obj3 = {a: 1, c:3, d:5};
var obj4 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7, z:20};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj3, obj4)); // {a:4, b:6, c:10, d:5, z:20}
```

Comment: What is `var val = myObj[key + key2];` supposed to do? `key` and `key2` are strings. And why `var val = ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop here since you can use the key to index/access the values from both objects. Since `object1` may have more properties than `object2` and vice versa, you can first merge all object properties from both `object1` and `object2` into a merged object using the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Once you have a merged object, you can iterate the keys of the object using `for...in`, and grab the key from both `object1` and `object2` to add to the new resulting object. One object may not have the other key, so you can default the value to `0` using `|| 0` if it doesn't exist.

See example below:

```js
function mergeCounters (object1, object2) {
  const merged = {...object1, ...object2};
  const result = {};
  for(const key in merged) {
    result[key] = (object1[key] || 0) + (object2[key] || 0);
  }
  return result;
}

var obj1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3};
var obj2 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj1, obj2)); // {a:4, b:8, c:10}

var obj3 = {a: 1, c:3, d:5};
var obj4 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7, z:20};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj3, obj4)); // {a:4, b:6, c:10, d:5, z:20}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy to achieve, the process goes as follows.

- copy the values of `object1` to `myObj`
- iterate all of `object2`, if the key is already present add it, otherwise set it

```js
function mergeCounters (object1, object2) {
   const myObj = { ...object1 };
   for(var key in object2) {
      myObj[key] = (myObj[key] || 0) + object2[key]
   }
   return myObj;
}

var obj1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3};
var obj2 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj1, obj2)); // {a:4, b:8, c:10}

var obj3 = {a: 1, c:3, d:5};
var obj4 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7, z:20};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj3, obj4)); // {a:4, b:6, c:10, d:5, z:20}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce version of [Nick Parsons' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66454160/295783)

```js
function mergeCounters (object1, object2) {
  return Object.keys({...object1, ...object2}) // collect all keys of both objects
    .reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = (object1[key] || 0) + (object2[key] || 0); // add the object values together if they exist
      return acc;
    },{})
}

var obj1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3};
var obj2 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj1, obj2)); // {a:4, b:8, c:10}

var obj3 = {a: 1, c:3, d:5};
var obj4 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7, z:20};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj3, obj4)); // {a:4, b:6, c:10, d:5, z:20}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, for older browsers, that gives the expected results:

```js
function mergeCounters(o1, o2, firstSum) {
  let sum = firstSum || {};
  for (let prop in o1) {
    sum[prop] = sum[prop] === undefined ?
      o1[prop] || 0 + o2[prop] || 0 :
      sum[prop] += o1[prop] || o2[prop];
  }
  if (!firstSum) {
    mergeCounters(o2, o1, sum);
  }
  return sum;
};
var obj1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3};
var obj2 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj1, obj2)); // {a:4, b:8, c:10}

var obj3 = {a: 1, c:3, d:5};
var obj4 = {a: 3, b:6, c:7, z:20};
console.log(mergeCounters(obj3, obj4)); // {a:4, b:6, c:10, d:5, z:20}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can help here

1. `Object.entries()`: get all properties and their values
2. `Array.prototype.concat()`: combine the properties of both objects
3. `Array.prototype.reduce()`: add the properties into one new object and combine the value of properties with the same name

```js
function mergeCounters(objectA, objectB) {
  const entriesA = Object.entries(objectA);
  const entriesB = Object.entries(objectB);

  return entriesA.concat(entriesB)
    .reduce((result, current) => {
      const key = current[0];
      const value = current[1];

      if (typeof result[key] !== "undefined") {
        result[key] = result[key] + value;
      } else {
        result[key] = value;
      }

      return result
    }, {});
}

var obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var obj2 = { a: 3, b: 6, c: 7 };
console.log(mergeCounters(obj1, obj2)); // {a:4, b:8, c:10}

var obj3 = { a: 1, c: 3, d: 5 };
var obj4 = { a: 3, b: 6, c: 7, z: 20 };
console.log(mergeCounters(obj3, obj4)); // {a:4, b:6, c:10, d:5, z:20}
```

Comment: This could be heavily minimized but imho this is easier to understand for a beginner.

Comment: yes [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66454778/295783)